# document language meta not included by default

Tags: apache-tika, language-detection

I'm playing with Apache Tika (1.13) and noticed that the language tag not is included for any of the documents that I run through *tika-app --metadata*.

What is the proper way to include/force language detection for all documents? Is it possible to do though configuration or may be I have to add a new parser adding this meta data, or override an existing parser in the chain?

Thanks!

Comment: Try with the `--language` option instead?

Comment: i did, but then it only returns the language info, while i need all the meta data (language included)

Comment: Run it twice? Or write your own code that calls Tika that requests both?

Comment: well, that's what my question is about ))